# Remove Bold from textview without changing other attributes

Tags: java, android, textview

I use `setTypeface` to set a text bold (or italics, or other of the typeface attributes)

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.label);
...
tv.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
...
```

How do I remove only the bold attribute, without changing other attributes that might have been set so far?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
tv.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);
```

This would set the style back to normal without changing color or size.

But you can't mix bold/italic/underline text this way.  If you specify BOLD, all of the text will be bold.  If you want to mix the style of the text I suggest using HTML to style the text, and then use the following code.

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourStringAsHtml));
```

Comment: I thought about `Html.fromHtml()` as well, but this makes toggling bold italic and underline seperatly rather difficult, doesn't it?

Comment: It is not straightforward, but I don't believe you have another option, because the text style is for all of the text in the TextView. Depending on what you are trying to do, you could modify your layout and have separate views for what can be bold/underline/italic, but that would only work for a very static use case.

Comment: @Flynn81 that's what I though, if I set BOLD_ITALIC or BOLD and want to dismiss the BOLD part, I have to be aware of the current state of the text, unless I get the typeface and ask `isBold()` , `isItalic()`

Comment: Yeah, no pretty solution that I can think of for what you are trying to achieve. Good luck, maybe someone else can suggest a better idea.

Answer (score 6):

just create a new Typeface can make `bold` back to `normal`

```java
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.create(tv.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL), Typeface.NORMAL);
tv.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 2):

this chunk of code removed the old Typeface **setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);**

For keeping the old you should call

> setTextViewStyle(textView, isBold);

```
private void setTextViewStyle(TextView view, boolean isBold){
    if (view == null)
        return;

    // if old typeface is null create new Typeface bold or def
    Typeface oldTypeface = view.getTypeface() != null ? view.getTypeface() :
            (isBold ? Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD : Typeface.DEFAULT);

    view.setTypeface(
            Typeface.create(oldTypeface, isBold ? Typeface.BOLD : Typeface.NORMAL)
    );
}
```

Comment: how to do this for italic?

Answer (score 1):

like me, if you want to preserve the custom font you have set to the TextView and just remove BOLD attribute, you can try

```
tv.getPaint().setFakeBoldText(false)
```

Doing following removed the custom font I had set to the TextView.

```
tv.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);
```