# How do I change the typeface of a textview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a textview that is normally bold, as defined in xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
```

The text is used in an adapter. depending on the data I am printing in the text, I need to change the style from bold to normal. And so I use

```
viewsHolder.myTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
viewsHolder.myTextView.setText(myString);
```

But the call to change Typeface to DEFAULT never takes effect. Does anyone know why?

Also if I change DEFAULT to NORMAL, it does not compile at all.

I am looking for a solution as simple as one line of code, similar to as I have already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Bold from textview without changing other attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261207/remove-bold-from-textview-without-changing-other-attributes)

Comment: try this , 
viewsHolder.myTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

Comment: another way is to define two TextView one is Bold another one Normal just show - hide as per your requirement...