# How to clear fontFamily after setup in XML

Tags: android, fonts, font-family

I have some layout already setup font for textView.

```
android:fontFamily="@font/cookie_regular"
```

But i want to have more setting option to clear/set default font when i need in Java code.
Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: try with setTypeface

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17261322/8089770

Answer (score 0):

Call this method when you want to change some textview to a different font.

```
public void change_font(){
               //if or switch statement may be needed or not.
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/THE_FONT_I_HAVE_CREATED_OR_DOWNLOADED.ttf");
               //FYI font is a file you can create in your res folder.
    myTEXTVIEW.setTypeface(custom_font);
}
```

Lastly more information about downloadable fonts 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts